# How can I mount a partition from dd-created image of a block device (e.g. HDD) under Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, disk-image

I have an image of the entire disk created using **dd**. The disk structure follows:

```
kent@cow:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 750.1 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b8508

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           5       90872   729929303+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2           90873       91201     2642692+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5           90873       91201     2642661   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

The image was created using:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=image750.img
```

How would I, if it is possible, mount /dev/sda1 from the image so that I'm able to read the contents?

It's not an option to clone the HDD again, I know how to do it if I had only cloned the single partition by itself. I hope it's still possible with the current image.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image || http://superuser.com/questions/117136/how-can-i-mount-a-partition-from-dd-created-image-of-a-block-device-e-g-hdd-u || http://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/loopback-mounting-individual-partitions-from-within-a-file-that-contains-a-parti

Answer (score 104):

Nowadays, there is a better way, no need to use offsets or kpartx anymore:

```
losetup --partscan --find --show disk.img

mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

to free up loop0, use after umount:

```
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, losetup doesn't provide a --partscan option.

Comment: @Cutter it was added in util-linux 2.21, Ubuntu 16.04. :-)

Comment: Having used `kpartx` first, which mounts the partitions like `/dev/mapper/loop3p1`, I just want to point out that `losetup` creates the devices like `/dev/loop0p1`.  The answer notes that, but I read over it probably 10 times. :/

Comment: `losetup --partscan --find --show disk.img` might give you `/dev/loop1`, in which case you'll need `mount /dev/loop1p1 /mnt`.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the virtual block devices after you're finished at all?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this problem today and wanted to update the answers just as a reminder for myself.
Instead of calculating the offset on your own, you can use a tool that provides you with mountable devices from a dd image: kpartx

http://robert.penz.name/73/kpartx-a-tool-for-mounting-partitions-within-an-image-file/

http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx

In the given case, it would need something like

```
sudo kpartx -a image750.img
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mount/point -o loop,ro
```

where loop1p1 stands for the first partition, loop1p2 for the second, etc.

Answer (score 13):

You've got the first part:  fdisk -l to find the start offset.  Take that number, multiply by 512, and you'll get the offset option to mount.  So, for sda1 in your case, 5 * 512 = 2560.  Then run the mount:

```
mount -o loop,offset=2560 -t auto /path/to/image.dd /mount/point
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe [loopmounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device#Example) is the answer -

```
sudo mkdir /path/to/dir/
mount -o loop example.img /path/to/dir/
```

The above should mount it under that directory.

This should unmount it:

```
umount /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score 5):

Loopmounting is only part of the answer.

Look at http://wiki.edseek.com/guide:mount_loopback#accessing_specific_partitions_in_the_image for help on specifying the partition. I **think** mount -o loop,offset=32256 /path/to/image750.img /mnt will work for you. but you really should read the mentioned tutorial.

Comment: the offset looks wrong; that corresponds to a partition start of 63 (<i>63 * 512 = 32256</i>).  the offset in baumgart's answer looks more correct for this situation.  the link is a good reference, but it'd be a better answer if you took the time to summarize the steps or commands needed for this procedure.  thanks!

Comment: This is a good example of link rot. That page is gone.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20141213021001/http://wiki.edseek.com:80/guide:mount_loopback or this lists multiple variants to mount https://tinyapps.org/docs/mount_partitions_from_disk_images.html

Answer (score 1):

**`losetup -P` automation**

Method mentioned by https://superuser.com/a/684707/128124 (added in util-linux v2.21, added Ubuntu 16.04) , here are functions to automate it further. Usage:

```
$ los my.img
/dev/loop0
/mnt/loop0p1
/mnt/loop0p2

$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
/whatever
/files
/youhave
/there

$ sudo losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                                                      DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /full/path/to/my.img

$ # Cleanup.
$ losd 0
$ ls /mnt/loop0p1
$ ls /dev | grep loop0
loop0
```

Source:

```
los() (
  img="$1"
  dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P "$img")"
  echo "$dev"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    echo "$dst"
    sudo mkdir -p "$dst"
    sudo mount "$part" "$dst"
  done
)
losd() (
  dev="/dev/loop$1"
  for part in "$dev"?*; do
    if [ "$part" = "${dev}p*" ]; then
      part="${dev}"
    fi
    dst="/mnt/$(basename "$part")"
    sudo umount "$dst"
  done
  sudo losetup -d "$dev"
)
```

**loop module max_part config**

Decent method before util-linux v2.21.

`loop` is a kernel module, built into the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.

If you configure it right, Linux automatically splits up the devices for you.

```
cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_part
```

says how many partitions `loop` devices can generate.

It is `0` by default on Ubuntu 14.04 which is why no auto-splitting happens.

To change it, we can either add:

```
options loop max_part=31
```

to a file in `/etc/modprobe`, or:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="loop.max_part=31"
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`.

How to set a module parameter is also covered at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/51226/how-to-add-kernel-module-parameters

After a reboot, when you do:

```
sudo losetup -f --show my.img
```

it mounts the image to a `/dev/loopX` device, and automatically mounts the partitions to `/dev/loopXpY` devices.

So this is the most convenient method if you are willing to reboot.

**See also**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/loopback-mounting-individual-partitions-from-within-a-file-that-contains-a-parti

Answer (score 0):

If you have User mode files system like fuse, then in desktop environments likes Gnome and have installed tool like gnome-disk-image-mounter, then it without even root by right click and open with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo kpartx -a image750.img
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mount/point -o loop,ro
```

allowed me to mount an image of a damaged partition caused by multiple IO errors. there was no other way for me to mount. thanks so much for this answer @GrGr

You just helped me recover about a Tb of data that was level 10 crucial.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207102)