# BSOD after update, now crashes if a specific HDD is plugged

Tags: windows-10, bsod, mbr, gpt

I was getting a bootloop with "automatic repair" I finally managed to fix it by leaving only my OS ssd plugged in and booting to windows, then it showed a "something went wrong rolling back" or something similar blue screen and I managed to boot to windows, then updated and everything went good so I plugged all the disks back.

My disks are:

- 1TB SSD with OS
- 1TB HDD 7200 Seagate
- 4TB HDD 5600 WD Blue

I can plug the WD and still make it to Windows, if I plug the Seagate through USB I get a BSOD with the code PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA AND EUBKMON.SYS

If I leave it plugged in from the start I get a bootloop.

How can I fix this? I can probably plug the Seagate to a linux laptop I have.

I'm pretty sure the seagate is MBR while the other 2 are GPT, not sure if it has anything to do with the crash as it was working fine a few days ago.

#### Edit:

Files found on the seagate:

- bootmgr
- BOOTNXT
- BOOTSECT.BAK
- EUMONBMP.SYS
- RTCNS
- SYSTEM VOLUME INFORMATION (DIR)
- Boot (DIR)

Comment: See if you can view it under Linux, but *do not attempt repairs of the FS* under Linux. Try to recover data.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik updated main post, I checked on linux, it says partition MBR NTFS/exFAT/HPFS (Bootable)

Comment: Then I'd use dd on Linux to make an exact image, and salvage data *from the mounted image* (https://superuser.com/questions/117136/how-can-i-mount-a-partition-from-dd-created-image-of-a-block-device-e-g-hdd-u). You're then free to try to *restore* from the image, or remove all partitions, save, create all needed partitions and format them.

Comment: I don-t have anything too important in there, I deleted the files I found and used gdisk to convert from MBR to GPT with `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb`, now I can connect the HDD without problems and access all files from windows.

Comment: Great! glad that worked under Linux.

Comment: @Daviid Please convert your last comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific BSOD error code is almost certainly due to a bad driver; it does not indicate anything wrong with your drive.

`PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` basically means that the driver tried to access invalid memory. That usually means there's a bug in the driver.

[A quick internet search will tell you](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-cannot-restart-and-automatic-fix-doesnt/7e5b2629-0d4f-4cd6-8ce1-5479d27ef909) that EUBKMON.SYS is part of something called "EaseUS Todo Backup Monitor". It is quite possible that you're encountering a bug present only in the code that processes MBR drives. Either way, it would probably be a good idea to remove the faulty software.

Answer (score 0):

Files found on the seagate:

- bootmgr
- BOOTNXT
- BOOTSECT.BAK
- EUMONBMP.SYS
- RTCNS
- SYSTEM VOLUME INFORMATION (DIR)
- Boot (DIR)

I deleted these and then used the `gdisk` command on linux to convert the HDD from MBR to GPT.

After that I was able to connect the HDD to my windows computer without problem and without data loss.